# disable validation for dropdownlist in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

i have dropdownlist  list in my cshtml view .
 i want to make its selection is optional, added validation.js file 
But when i click on submit button its not going to the controller
Here is the code

@Html.LabelFor(model => model.GeneralLedgerID, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-6" })

@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.GeneralLedgerID, Model.GeneralLedger, "", new { @class = " form-control valid", @data_val = "true"})

how to disable validation for dropdownlist??

Comment: please show the, your biding model and what you get on submit click?

Comment: If it's optional, is GeneralLedgerID defined as nullable? Please post model code, and format it, and clarify what "it's not going to the controller" means. Do you get an error? What did you expect to happen and what actually happened?